# npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-fibers, fibers

I'm trying to install Sunbird on my laptop by referring [document](http://www.sunbird.org/developer-docs/installation/install_sbportal/).
But getting error on `npm install` step

1. `gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
   gyp ERR! configure error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: unexpected end of file
   gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:134:17)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-37-generic
   gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
   gyp ERR! cwd /home/ttpllt23/GIT/snd-setup/sunbird-portal/src/node_modules/fibers
   gyp ERR! node -v v9.3.0
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   node-gyp exited with code:`

And

2. `npm ERR! file sh
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
   npm ERR! syscall spawn
   npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install:`node build.js || nodejs build.js
   `npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.15 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

I'm using 
ubuntu v16.04
node v9.3.0

Comment: Were you able to fix this errors? It would be helpful if you can suggest workaround for this or how you able to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with node version. It should be 6.x.x only

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed below dependencies, and then try installing fibers `npm i fibers` in your u Ubuntu system.

1. `sudo npm install - g node-gyp`
2. `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. Is there any other solution?