# npm ERR!: code 127. gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, node-gyp

I'm getting the following error while doing `npm install`:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/jesusjimenez/projects/project/node_modules/fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:453:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:665:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-48-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/jesusjimenez/projects/project/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/jesusjimenez/projects/project/node_modules/fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-gyp exited with code: 1
npm ERR! Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
npm ERR! would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
npm ERR! build environment--
npm ERR! Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
npm ERR! Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
npm ERR! RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 
npm ERR! Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
npm ERR! sh: 1: nodejs: not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jesusjimenez/.npm/_logs/2021-03-30T21_32_02_097Z-debug.log
```

I'm not completely sure what is breaking the install, if fibers or somehow that python `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
However, trying to install fibers individually throws same error. `npm i -g fibers` doesn't fix, neither changing `npm configure set python /path/to/python`. Deleting fibers momentarily keeps throwing same Python `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error, this time with another node_module.

Comment: Solved [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49536033/13784272) downgrading node version [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7718438/13784272).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the **solution** to this issue.

**Explanation:**

Notice this part of your NPM error log:

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

This means your code is trying to install node-gyp of the version 3.8.0

What is probably happening (this was in my case) you have a **wrong** NodeJS **version**, for node-gyp.

I searched for the right version of NodeJS for node-gyp 3.8.0, and the answer is below.

**Solution:**

1. Uninstall current NodeJS version
2. Install NodeJS Version **6.17.1** (if you need multiple NodeJS versions use NVM tool (Instructions For Windows/Linux/MacOS) https://www.nubo.eu/Install-Multiple-Node-Versions-On-Windows/
3. Run `npm install` in your project again

Comment: Downgrading indeed solved the problem, in my case I've used Node version manager as this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7718438/13784272)

Comment: In my case I downgraded to Node 14.17.6 (npm 6.14.15)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I set a PATH variable incorrectly which meant npm and node couldn't be found correctly.

To diagnose this, I ran

```
npm --version
node --version
```

It said command not found, so I checked `env | grep PATH` which showed me that the location of npm and node weren't on PATH as they needed to be. Once I fixed that, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same/similar issue without making any changes to version of node. I hate to be that guy, but after a day of struggling with it I decided to restart my machine. That fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `node-gyp` tries to build with `Python 2` syntax: `print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];` which throws an error probably because you have `Python 3` on your computer.

This usually occurs when installing an outdated `npm` module which is not compatible with the current `Node` version on your system. Try installing `Python 2` and set it to the path, or locate the offending module in `package.json` and then upgrade the version number to the one that is compatible with your current Node version.