# Getting Error While Installing Node Modules:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-gyp

I get code from my buddy and trying to setup on my system (React Js), but each time I try I face the same issue even I install python@0.3.10 My other system specs are Mac Os, Node Version: v19.7.0, NPM Version: v8.1.0, I also try with yarn but can't find any solution, can you help me with this:

My Package.json:

```js
{
    "name": "dogerush-final",
    "homepage": ".",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
        "@react-spring/parallax": "^9.4.5",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.8.0",
        "aos": "^2.3.4",
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
        "country-telephone-data": "^0.6.3",
        "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
        "gsap": "^3.10.4",
        "i18n-iso-countries": "^7.6.0",
        "is-hex-prefixed": "^1.0.0",
        "is-in-browser": "^2.0.0",
        "jss": "^10.10.0",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-easy-marquee": "^1.2.4",
        "react-fast-marquee": "^1.3.2",
        "react-ga": "^3.3.1",
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
        "react-intersection-observer": "^9.4.3",
        "react-mailchimp-form": "^1.0.2",
        "react-parallax": "^3.5.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "react-scroll-parallax": "^3.3.1",
        "react-select": "^5.7.3",
        "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
        "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
        "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
        "swiper": "^8.2.6",
        "typewriter-effect": "^2.19.0",
        "use-mailchimp-form": "^3.0.3",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "web3": "^1.8.0",
        "web3modal": "^1.9.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "zip": "cd build && zip -qr build.zip .",
        "deploy": "npm run build && npm run zip",
        "deploy:staging": "npm run build:staging && npm run zip",
        "postinstall": "patch-package",
        "archive": "git archive -o release.zip HEAD"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
        "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
        "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^3.1.1",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
        "truffle": "^5.6.4",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "url": "^0.11.0"
    }
}
```

```
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[6/21] ⡀ swiper
[8/21] ⡀ bufferutil
[3/21] ⡀ node-sass
[4/21] ⡀ core-js-pure
error /Users/macbookpro/Documents/Fiverr/5:2023/dogerush-final/node_modules/websocket/node_modules/bufferutil: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: node-gyp-build
Arguments:
```

Here is with Yran:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878986/npm-err-code-127-gyp-err-stack-error-command-failed have you tried going through some of the threads here